# Manually extract EXIF from stream and attach it to JPEG file

Tags: java, android, bitmap, exif

Given an image `Uri`, I need to save the image to my app's cache directory. I am extracting the `bitmap` from the `Uri` using `InputStream` because the `Uri` could be coming from `MediaStore` or other app's content `Uri` (example Google Photos) and a filePath can't be safely derived in all cases.

Since there is no method to read `EXIF` from `InputStream` or `FileDescriptor` in android `Marshmallow` and below, I am using [this](https://github.com/dotloop/aosp-exif) library which has an Exif constructor for `InputStream`.

What I want is, when I extract the `bitmap` from the `Uri` and write it to a `JPEG` file in my cache directory, I want to stitch all the `EXIF` data I got from the `InputStream` to this `JPEG` file because of some business requirements (rotation and lat-long mostly).

I can't figure out the correct way to this using the above library (not very proficient in `EXIF`). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right approach for this type of problem. The stream already is a JPG with all the EXIF data into it. You just have to copy the stream directly to your apps cache.

Something like that:

```
// in is the inputstream that you got from the Uri
// dst is a file to your app internal cache
public void copy(Uri uri, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

After this execution a copy of the original JPG is saved in your app local cache, including all its EXIF. After that, if you want a Bitmap (to show on the screen, apply effects, or whatever) then you load the bitmap from your JPG copy.